# Batch file that runs upon accessing folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory, directory, automatic-storage

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a batch file that automatically executes when I open a directory. I have no clue as to how this would be done.

I want it to do this whether it is accessed through cmd/.exe/.bat/mouse

Comment: You would have to use WMI, which can monitor conditions you set, then take an action. I don't know how, but this is one thing I know WMI is made to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This isn't possible using a batch file. (In fact, I don't think it's possible at all without writing a shell extension, which would require an actual programming language.)

Comment: actually it is i figured it out myself. @kenwhite